# Problem running rman in cron

Tags: rhel, cron, backup, oracle

I have a problem with script scheduled in cron. In cron I have following line:

```
33 09 * * 1-5 oracle /data1/backup/scripts-test/rman.sh > /data1/backup/log.txt 2> /data1/backup/log_err.txt
```

As you see I have to use oracle user to run rman script. 
RMAN.SH looks as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME="/data1/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1"
ORACLE_SID="eelxtest"
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
now="$(date)"
logloc="/data1/backup/scripts-test/log"
rmanscript="/data1/backup/scripts-test"
jboss="/usr/JBossEAP/jboss-eap-6.4/bin"
ip="x.x.x.x"
ServerGroup="EELX-Server-Group-Test"
logfile="$logloc/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')_log.txt"
echo "============================================" | tee -a "$logfile"
date | tee -a "$logfile"
echo "STEP1 closing JBoss Server Group" | tee -a "$logfile"
$jboss/jboss-cli.sh --controller=$ip --connect /server-group=$ServerGroup:stop-servers | tee -a "$logfile"
echo "STEP2 oracle backup. See rman log." | tee -a "$logfile"
**$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rman msglog /data1/backup/scripts-test/log/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')_rman.log cmdfile=$rmanscript/rman_backup.cmd**
echo "STEP3 starting jboss Server Group" | tee -a "$logfile"
$jboss/jboss-cli.sh --controller=$ip --connect /server-group=$ServerGroup:start-servers | tee -a "$logfile"]
```

*rman_backup.cmd* is:

```
connect target /
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
run
{
allocate channel ch1 device type disk;
backup as compressed backupset full database format '/data1/extDirectories/xxx/yyy/oracle/test/%T_eelxtest_full_%u.bkp';
backup format '/data1/extDirectories/xxx/yyy/oracle/test/%T_archivelog_eelxtest_%u.bkp' >>(archivelog all delete input);
backup spfile;
backup current controlfile format '/data1/extDirectories/xxx/yyy/oracle/test/%T_ora_ctl_file_eelxtest_%u.bkp';
release channel ch1;
}
sql 'alter database open'
```

As a result of job in cron  are following messages:

```
Message file RMAN<lang>.msb not found
Verify that ORACLE_HOME is set properly
```

So I have verified `ORACLE_HOME` on both profiles oracle and root and it is in place in *.bash_profile*.
Furthermore there is nothing mentioned in rman trace or log because rman didn't start at all.

Please help.

Comment: Does `export ORACLE_HOME` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas,

possible you must export the variable ORACLE_HOME, by;

```
export ORACLE_HOME
```

after declaration in script: rman.sh

Comment: when running script in cron, you have less environment.

Comment: yes, you are right. Missing `export`. Thank you